# Use SSIS to transfer file from FTP to Server

Tags: ssis

This is probably too simplistic a question but here goes.

I have a client that will drop xls files into a folder on our FTP site.  I need to check if a file exists, I need to move it from the FTP folder to a folder on the server.  Once the processing is done, I need to send another (but different) xls file back to a folder on the same FTP server.

I can see that there is an FTP task and I can connect to the FTP site, but I am unsure on how to specify where to send the file and also how to only select a file at a time.

I think if I just concentrate on the first part, I can work on getting the file back as a second step.

So the end result is to check the folder on the FTP site, if a file exists move it to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SSIS FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137656.aspx) task wraps the basic FTP syntax you would use if you were connecting to the FTP site interactively.  Here's a [review of basic FTP syntax](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html).

So here's what you should be looking for when you're editing the FTP task.  1) The task needs to log into the FTP server, 2) it needs to know that it is performing a GET operation, 3) it needs to know the path and filename of the file it is supposed to retrieve from the FTP server, and 4) it needs to know where to drop the file on the local server.

So, in the FTP Task Editor, you want to go to the General tab and create an FTP connection.  Then go to the File Transfer tab, and then set the  "Operation" -> "Receive files", and fill in values for the Local Path and the Remote Path.  (Or you can keep those paths in SSIS variables and have the task get them from there.)

The IsTransferAscii setting is False by default.  This means it will assume it is transferring a binary file.  Alternatively, if you tell it to treat it like an Ascii file, it will try to fix the line endings to account for the different combinations of carriage return and line feed characters used by various operating systems.  You don't want that if you want to transfer the file verbatim, but you might want it if you're going back and forth between Windows and Linux or something.

You should also learn a little interactive FTP syntax.  I often use this to figure out why SSIS is having a problem transferring files.  Go to the command prompt and type "ftp".  You can then type "?" to see a list of commands.  Or just type "ftp yourservername", log in, and use cd and ls to walk around the directory structure and see what's there.

Comment: Thanks criticalfix this is perfect.  I was playing with it at the same time.  I now can download the file as well as delete the files after they have been downloaded.